# PHP include file doesn't seem to be recognized

Tags: php

I have the following PHP files, which all use include_once when including:

- FileA
- FileB
- FileC
- FileX

FileB includes:
- FileA
- FileC

FileC includes:
- FileA

FileX includes:
- FileB
- FileA
- FileC

FileC, which has an object that inherits from a class defined in FileA, does not see the class, and I get the following error:
Fatal error: Class 'TheBaseObject' not found in /(my path)/FileC.php on line 6

Before, FileB did not include FileC, and it worked. If I change the order of includes in FileX to the following it will work:
- FileA
- FileB
- FileC

Unfortunately, there are many FileX's in my webservice, and it doesn't seem like changing the order there is the right way to solve the problem. Why is FileC not seeing FileA? What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: If you showed us some actual code the demonstrates your problem you may get some answers rather than just guesses.

Comment: what you tired so far??

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's just a question of inheritance, exactly as described.

Comment: @Abdulla As stated in the question, change the order in FileX fixes it, but I don't understand why.

Comment: please, add your PHP version in your question

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with files that do only what you've described? I.e. FileA containing one class definition, FileB only including FileA+FileC and FileC including FIleA+instantiating an instance of the class defined in FileA. Nothing more.

Comment: what you've described has worked for me, i wasn't able to reproduce your bug... at least in php 5.6.12

Comment: If your files are named like that, or you can't reproduce the class relation, then your best option would be using a map-based autoloader instead of manual includes.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, changing the includes use the DIR variable fixed it. They now look like this:

```
include_once __DIR__ .'/FileA.php';
```

Hope it helps someone else.